# How to tell CMake to download external projects before compiling my sources

Tags: cmake

I have my own code which depends on third-party libraries, such as yaml-cpp for example. I want to download these third-party libraries before compiling my own sources. However, I don't manage to do it with CMake.

I managed to download yaml-cpp like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(yaml-cpp
                URL https://yaml-cpp.googlecode.com/files/yaml-cpp-0.5.1.tar.gz
                PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/yaml-cpp
                CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
```

But when I type

```
cmake ..
make
```

my sources are compiled before. Actually, yaml-cpp is downloaded at the very last step.

Do you know how to tell CMake to download third-party libraries at the very first building step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ExternalProject` creates a target. You can make your first target, e.g. your library, dependent from that target. Then it gets downloaded before you start building your library.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it works!
I just added the line

```
add_dependencies(my_project yaml-cpp)
```

and yaml-cpp was downloaded before compiling my_project.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to stackoverflow. It seems I cannot upvote your answer because my "reputation" is too low. Could you explain me how to accept your answer please?

Comment: Oh I managed to upvote your answer because my reputation is higher than few hours ago. So, I juste need to know how to accept your answer.

Comment: To clarify: The project needs to be a dependency of a target, not a CMake project. i.e. my_project needs to be a target, not a project.